# I messed up migration in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

I am new to rails and I wanted to add a string one of the migration file. Unfortunately, I did not know that it's very risky to play with migration.

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

I believe I used `rake db:rollback` and I used `rake db:redo` and nothing is changing I keep getting the same error

When I tried `rake db:migrate:status`, that's what I get:

```
database: /home/ubuntu/workspace/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20161022035511  Create posts
   up     20161022044605  Devise create users
   up     20161022045410  Add user id to post
   up     20161022050429  Add name to user
   up     20161022054826  Add attachment image to posts
   up     20161022170851  Create comments
  down    20161022184713  Acts as votable migration
  down    20161223064636  Add cached votes to posts
```

Here's the content for `AddCachedVotesToPosts`:

```
class AddCachedVotesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_total, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_score, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_down, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average, :float, :default => 0.0
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_total
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_score
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_up
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_down
    add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_score
    add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_total
    add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_average

    # Uncomment this line to force caching of existing votes
    # Post.find_each(&:update_cached_votes)
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_total
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_score
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_up
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_down
    remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score
    remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total
    remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average
  end
end
```

This is what i get in rails c:
Please help me out!

Comment: What do you get when you run `bundle exec rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20161223064636` ?

Comment: This http://i.imgur.com/27HtEdJ.png

Comment: I assume your `rake db:migrate:status` still shows **down** for migration `VERSION=20161223064636` . As per the error, you do have the column `cached_votes_total` already added to your `posts` table.

Comment: You are correct

Comment: If your migration `VERSION=20161223064636` is still **down** , I would recommend you to just remove that migration file. Instead, write a new migration to `change_column` as you need **OR** create new migration files to remove existing columns and add them again!

Comment: How to do so? I have heard that it is not recommended to remove a migration file.

Comment: If your migration status is **down** and you don't need it, better to just remove it! You can simply remove the migration file `db/migrate/20161223064636_add_cached_votes_to_posts.rb` .

Comment: Can i do a rake db:rollback, then do bundle exec rake db:drop bundle exec rake db:create bundle exec rake db:migrate?

Comment: And then add a new one again? Simple as that?

Comment: yes, it is as simple as that.  You do not need to remove the entire db and create it again!

Comment: I deleted and created a new one with the same name. However, I still get the same error and the migration is still down

Comment: Can you please post your new migration file content ? Also, open `rails console` and type `Post.column_names`, please add this result to your question as well.

Comment: here is the migration content(was not able to run rake db:migrate for them) http://i.imgur.com/FuXvyK7.png

and here's the results for rails console: http://i.imgur.com/0cTZ6QY.png

Comment: Just remove the migration file you have now created, check my answer below and let me know if you still find any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two migrations as follows:

1. `rails g migration RemoveCachedVotesTotalFromPost` :

Its content should be:

```
def change
  remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_total
end
```

2. `rails g migration AddCachedVotesToPost` :

Its content should be:

```
def self.up
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_total, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_score, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_votes_down, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total, :integer, :default => 0
  add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average, :float, :default => 0.0
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_total
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_score
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_up
  add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_down
  add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_score
  add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_total
  add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_average
end

def self.down
  remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_total
  remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_score
  remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_up
  remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_down
  remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score
  remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total
  remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average
end
```

Comment: then run db:migrate?

Comment: also should `remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_total` be inside the `def change`?

Comment: @hekmat: yes run `rake db:migrate` . did this work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your local database and not production then to fix this.

You can do 
bundle exec rake db:drop
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate

[Warning] This ll delete all you have stored in your local db.

Comment: What do you mean by local or production?

Comment: My bad, development vs production. In production as mentioned in the warning it is not preferable to delete all the data (for that matter any data). In development environment, its almost everyday practice.

Comment: Please checkout the edit there are three commands 1. bundle exec rake db:drop 2. bundle exec rake db:create 3. bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: Great!! I ran the three commands and I got my `Acts_as_votable_migration` up but the last one is still down. Do I do the same process again?

Comment: just bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: `Add_cached_votes_to_posts` is still down even after running bundle exec db:migrate

Comment: Do you mind sharing the content of the migration Add cached votes to posts ?

Comment: rails console
>> require "db/migrate/20161223064636_add_cached_votes_to_posts.rb"
>> AddCachedVotesToPosts.up


Please use your absolute path while doing require

Comment: I am sorry. I am not familiar with absolute path! What is that

Comment: okay do rails console over there do the follow
require "#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/20161223064636_add_cached_votes_to_posts.rb" after this do AddCachedVotesToPosts.up

Comment: Hi, I first part worked but the second did not. here's a pic http://i.imgur.com/t1Spvav.png

Comment: Thank you, so much for your help I got it fixed